# Magento blank alert in checkout step 1 (save billing)

Tags: magento, checkout, onepage-checkout

ver :- Magento 1.9

file :- `/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php`

I am getting blank alert box at checkout 1st step.

ajax :- "/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/" `Returns {"error":-1,"message":""}`

`$customerErrors = $customerForm->validateData($customerData);`

(line no. 383, `function _validateCustomerData`)

returns

`Array
(
    [0] => 
)`

This is happening with users having work email address only, with @gmail.com users every thing is working fine.

Comment: Try to debug by enable error reporting

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was some of the default shipping methods, i disabled UPS/USPS shipping methods (System> Configuration>Shipping Methods) and it works.